# Is there a current mirror for "Refactor for Visual C++"?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, devexpress

Recently I came across a recommendation for a Visual Studio plugin called [**Refactor! For Visual C++**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb737896) that looks like it would be very useful in helping me tame a particularly pastalike legacy application that I've inherited. Unfortunately, the download links appear to be broken and I can't find a mirror anywhere online.

I've also tried to contact DevExpress, but they suggested that Refactor has been effectively discontinued by being rolled into CodeRush Express and that I use that. Since CodeRush does not support C++, and even further doesn't work with Visual Studio 2005, I am unable to use it.

Does anyone know of (or can provide) a mirror for the Refactor! for VC++ installer? I'm sure I'm not the only one who's stuck in VS2005 that would benefit from this tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevExpress responded to an issue in their tracker with a link to just the Refactor component. Unfortunately, I couldn't get it to work for me.

For posterity, here's the link they sent, and the issue ticket:

http://downloads.devexpress.com/DXperience/2011.2/7/RefactorCPP-11.2.7.exe

http://www.devexpress.com/issue=B208783

**Edit:** Before someone else says it, [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) *does* support Visual Studio 2005. I was interested in Refactor mostly for the fact that it <strike>is</strike> **was** a free product that I could use at work without having to go through purchasing and licensing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this plugin, which claims to support VS2005 and C++:

- [DevExpress Refactor! Pro for Visual Studio (Trial)](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1C5390EF-48A5-487C-9332-29B98EFECC22)

Comment: None of the currently-available DevExpress tools support VS2005. The MSDN page you linked does not provide a download, it merely links you to DevExpress's current site (where it's impossible to find and download old versions). Looks like we VS2005 users are locked out in the rain. =)